# Printing values for a range of numbers in C by calling the function

Tags: c, function, loops, if-statement

I'm doing a project to calculate a value, `ratio` here, I want to print the values of `ratio` in range within `3 to 5`.

I want to print the values for the range 3 to 5 such that if ratio< cratio, then ratios in ascending order within range from 3 to 5 should be printed. And if ratio> cratio then ratio should be in descending order within range from 5 to 3 should be printed.
Well I want to print only one set of values. I am getting both the set i.e ratios is printed as - 3.05,3.52,4.5,4.5,3.52,3.05 and so on.
Where to improve my code so that only `temp2`,`Ls`,`Lg` is shown for the ratio between `3 to 5`?

Here's my code:

```
float Calculate_RG(float r, int d, float cratio) {
    temp2 = d;
    y = ( pg / (p0 - pg) ) * (r / dm);
    LgD = 422 * ( (T * Z * Qg) / P ) * sqrt(y);
    Lg = LgD / temp2;
    Ls = Lg + (temp2 / 12);
    ratio = 12 * (Ls / temp2);

    if (ratio < 3) {
        temp2--;
        Calculate_RG(r, temp2--, ratio);
    } else if (ratio > 5) {
        temp2++;
        Calculate_RG(r, temp2, ratio);
    } else if (ratio > 3 && ratio < 5) {

        if (ratio > cratio) {
         printf("%d\t\t %0.2f\t\t %0.2f\t\t %0.2f\n\n", temp2, Lg, Ls, ratio);
            temp2--;
            Calculate_RG(r,temp2,ratio);
        } else if(ratio < cratio){
            printf("%d\t\t %0.2f\t\t %0.2f\t\t %0.2f\n\n", temp2, Lg, Ls, ratio);
            temp2++;
            Calculate_RG(r,temp2,ratio);            
        }
    }
cratio= ratio;
return cratio;
}
```

Where am I doing it wrong?? Suggestions Please!!

Comment: you never return a value...?

Answer (score 1):

*You declare your function to return float, but you never return values.*

Since C is pass-by-value, you are not changing values of the parameters inside your recursively called Calculate_RG.

What types are temp2, Lg, Ls, and ratio? Did you declare them outside this function, or ignore compiler warnings? What are the initial values of these (global) variables?

You use recursion for most branches of your code. You should have a clear condition (recursion guard) where the recursion should stop. What termination condition (values of ratio, et al) should cause your recursion to stop? Also one typically expects with recursion that you assign the return value from recursion to a variable your calling function either uses or returns.

Add a printf to display the various values just above your conditionals. You might also pass around a 'depth' parameter so that you can print your recursion depth (would help with debugging).

```
printf("r:%f, d:%d, cratio:%f, temp2:%d, Lg:%d, Ls:%d, ratio:%d\n",
    r,d,cratio,temp2,Lg,Ls,ratio);
if(ratio < 3)
```

That function would show you which branch(es) your function takes as it traverses down the recursion calls.

Your conditional expressions handle values for ratio,

- ratio < 3 (should this be <= 3?)
- ratio > 3 && ratio < 5 (should this be >= 3 or <= 5?)
- ratio > 5 (should this be >= 5?)

Your conditional would do nothing when ratio ==3 or ==5, so you should change boundary conditions to include these two points, or add an else to detect these cases. *(Always handle all domain values, even if you just provide a comment which states you are ignoring those values).*

- ratio == 3
- ratio == 5

You also do the same comparison for ratio and cratio,

- ratio > cratio
- ratio < cratio
- what do you want to do when ratio == cratio?

When your code decrements temp2 (twice), the first one could be --temp2 or temp2-- (no semantic difference), but the second decrements *after* you call the function, which has no subsequent effect on your program (temp2 is never used/referenced again). You do not print anything when ratio has a value <3 or >5.

```
    temp2--;
    Calculate_RG(r, temp2--, ratio);
....
    temp2++;
    Calculate_RG(r, temp2, ratio);
```

Comment: Yes! I declared  temp2, Lg, Ls, and ratio globally. There are no compiler warnings. FIRST condition- I just want to print the values of ratio, only if the ratio is between 3 to 5. Second Condtion- If between 3 to 5, then check if ratio is nearest to 3 or 5. Third condition- If nearest to 5, decrement temp2 and find the ratio up to 3. AND if nearest to 3, increment temp2 and find the ratio up to 5. But I am getting both the results in loop. How to stop that?

Comment: @SaumayPaul you won't get compiler warnings for using global variables in a recursive function. A global variable could be used to detect the recursion limit (such as depth) instead of weighing down the call with an unchanging argument. The compiler understands syntax, not the progam's logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Calculate_RG()` recursively but you don't define its variables locally. So they must be global variables and for that reason the code will fail.

Also you don't make any use of the function's return value.

Finally in 21st century never use `float` unless you can use `double`.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem I am getting here is that the numbers are printing for the both cases- ratio<cratio as well as ratio>cratio. How to stop that? I just want to print only one condtion.

Comment: Here's what i want- .FIRST condition- I just want to print the values of ratio, only if the ratio is between 3 to 5. Second Condtion- If between 3 to 5, then check if ratio is nearest to 3 or 5. Third condition- If nearest to 5, decrement temp2 and find the ratio up to 3. AND if nearest to 3, increment temp2 and find the ratio up to 5. But I am getting both the results in loop. How to stop that?

Comment: You already know the answer, look at what your code does after you print -- it calls Calculate_RG() again. What is your recursion termination condition?